# How can I enter the login and same time enter the OpenVPN server machine?

Tags: openvpn

How can I do to configure my client computer that is on the VPN network, and as you enter the login, it automatically now enters automatic mode server?

More or less like this video?

http://youtu.be/tSNCE6j2zxM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly?  You want to establish a VPN connection as soon as you log in?  There's a [`pam`-module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pam-openvpn/) that sounds promising:

> `pam-openvpn` is a Linux PAM-module which works together with OpenVPN.
>   With this `pam`-module it is possible to establish VPN connections when
>   a user logs into a system and tear down the connection when the user
>   logs off. This is ideal for mobile systems.

Comment: Ok, this pam-openvpn, that make if I login a specific user I connect to user in the same moment in a server openvpn? Like on this video?